# *ngIf causing android keyboard to close

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have the following code. Whenever the *ngIF is triggered and the div shows/hides the android keyboard is closed.

The code works correctly and shows/hides when it needs too but for some reason it's closing the keyboard and making typing in the ion-input very clunky. Any ideas on how to stop this?

```
<ion-input formControlName="LPQuantity" id="qtyTB" #qtyTB
            [(ngModel)]="receiving.checkinPageCheckIn.LPQuantity" type="number" placeholder="Quantity" name="LPQuantity"
            pattern="[0-9]+$" (ionBlur)="lpQuantityblured($event)" (ionFocus)="lpQuantityfocused($event)"></ion-input>
          <div class="data-error"
            *ngIf="(form.controls.LPQuantity.dirty || formValidate === 1) && form.controls.LPQuantity.invalid">
            Quantity must be &lt; MaxRcvQty({{receiving.checkinPageCheckIn?.MaxReceiveQuantity}}) </div>
```

Comment: i think input field gets focus out that might be the reason the keyboard gets closed, add a (blur) = "onBlur()" event in the textbox and see what happens

Comment: I was able to change it to [hidden] and that seems to work. We recently upgrade our applications from Ionic 3 --> Ionic 4. There must have been some change with the Angular framework because this worked in the previous application fine.

Comment: Okay, for a workarround use ngStyle instead of ngIf. To display none and block the div content